# Resources and tools for TCP tuning

Tags: windows, performance, networking, resources, tcp

I'm developing an application where, to satisfy the performance requirements, tuning of low-level network stuff (such as TCP window size etc) seems to be required.

I found the magnitude of my knowledge to be a bit better than "there's TCP and there's UDP", which is far from enough for this task.

What resources might I study to get a better knowledge of which aspects of TCP influence which performance characteristics in which usage scenarios (for example, how to decrease latency while transmitting 100kb packets to 1000 clients simultaneously on a 10gbit LAN), etc.?

What tools might help me? (I already know about Wireshark, but most probably I am not using it to its full potential)

Comment: This kind of tuning is usually platform specific so you might get more focused answers if you mention the platforms that you'll be using.

Comment: My platform is Windows Server 2008 R2, but 1) it might change and 2) my goal is rather to get a deep understanding of the platform-independent (protocol-related) parts and then proceed to platform specifics, armed with general knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First understand what you're doing:

- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)
- http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPWindowSizeAdjustmentandFlowControl.htm

Then understand how to look at what you're about to change:

- [http://www.wireshark.org/](https://www.wireshark.org/)
- [http://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Analyze_Sequence_Numbers](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Analyze_Sequence_Numbers)
- [http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865)

Then understand how to change things:

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819736.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20180109153523/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819736.aspx)
- [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2007/07/05/receive-window-auto-tuning-on-vista.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315170144/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2007/07/05/receive-window-auto-tuning-on-vista.aspx)

Since you're currently on a windows platform and you mention that you're "developing an application"... You probably also want to know about I/O Completion Ports and how you maximise data flow whilst conserving server resources using write completion driven flow control. I've written about these quite a bit and the last link is a link to my free high performance C++ client/server framework which may give you some pointers as to how to use IOCP efficiently.

- http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2005/11/windows-tcpip-server-performance.html
- http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2008/07/write-completion-flow-control.html
- http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html

And google is your friend...